# Managing Default Azure Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I signed up for an azure subscription and a default directory was provisioned for my subscription.

i cannot manage the default directory (e.g. create user or groups) via the azure portal. the portal replies with: "You do not have permission to access these resources."

while i understand that a admin role for an azure subscription is not the same as the admin role to manage an azure active directory; i am unable to find any MS guidance on how to assign the AD global admin role to my azure admin/subscription identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be a Global Administrator in the directory to create users.  Oddly though, you should already be one.  When you sign-up for an Azure subscription *you* are automatically added to the default directory as a Global Administrator.  At least that is how it used to work - perhaps it changed.

Anyway, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn468213.aspx) has the information you need and should get you going.

Comment: thanks. that makes total sense but for some reason i was added to the default directory as a user (role user that is).  perhaps something changed as you mentioned.  azure features do seem to be a rapidly moving target (mostly for the positive). i may have just subscribed at the wrong moment in time.

Comment: Did you use a Microsoft Account (aka LiveID) to sign up for Azure? Or a work or school account (aka AAD account)?